# How to insert zero in Required Nullable<int> type in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In my model I have

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="How Many Child Do You Have?")]
[Display(Name ="No Of Children")]
public Nullable<int> NoOFChildren { get; set; }
```

In my view I use following code

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NoOFChildren, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoOFChildren, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "No Of Children" } })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NoOFChildren, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is this code working fine if I enter number greater than zero but if I enter Zero it’s showing required error.
I want to insert zero as a default value. How I can do that in my code.

Comment: The code you have shown wont give an error if you enter `0` in the textbox (`0` is an `int`), only of you leave it empty. Do you have other validation attributes on the property?

Comment: No other validation attributes i have used with that field.

Comment: Do you have any javascript that may be interfering?

Comment: I find my solution. javascript  code was just deleting that value before posting the page. Thanks @StephenMuecke sir.

Comment: Then you should post an answer explaining how you solved it (why did you accept the answer you did?)

Answer (score 0):

how about using:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NoOFChildren, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "No Of Children", value=0 } })
```

### and you might want to create custom validation for the property

Populate model with default value in your controller / model

controller:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(){
var model = new Model(){
  NoOFChildren=0
}
return View(model);
}
```

or Model constructor

```
public class Model{
  public Model(){
    NoOFChildren=0;  // not the best solution as you might want to reuse the model
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to use Value=0 in htmlAttributes any other solution ?

Answer (score -1):

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="How Many Child Do You Have?")]
[Display(Name ="No Of Children")]
[DefaultValue(0)]
public Nullable<int> NoOFChildren { get; set; }
```

can you use like this?